# Arrays and C syntax

Tags: c, arrays, syntax

I have some code that isn't compiling, and I have been wracking my brain to fix it, I'm just a beginner programmer, and I feel like I have my fundamentals down, but for some reason I am getting errors like I forgot to put a semicolon and stuff, not sure why, or where that is, so if someone would be willing to proofread my work it would be greatly appreciated.

The errors appear to be occurring at the end of each statement in the main program, and error codes indicate I am forgetting a semicolon but I think I have them all so I don't quite understand my error.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    void printArrayValues(int array[], int num);


    void fillWithIndex(int array[], int num);


    int main(int argc, char * argv[])
    {
        int arr1[] = { 23, 21, 20, 27 };
        int arr2[] = { 5, 7, 9, 11, 13 };

            // Print the values in the first array, fill that array with
            // its indexes, and then print the values of the array
            // again.

            printArrayValues(arr1[], 4);
            fillWithIndex(arr1[], 4);
            printArrayValues(arr1[], 4);

            // Do similarly for the second array.

            printArrayValues(arr2[], 5);
            fillWithIndex(arr2[], 5);
            printArrayValues(arr2[], 5);

            return 0;
    }

    void printArrayValues(int array[], int num)

    {
        int i = 0;

        while (i < num)
        {
            printf("%d\n", array[i]);
            i++;
        }

        return;
    }


    void fillWithIndex(int array[], int num)
    {
        int i = 0;

        while (i < num)
        {
            array[i] = i;
            i++;
        }

        return;
    }
```

Comment: What's the error you're getting when you try to compile?

Comment: Visual Studio gives error C2605, ';': undeclared identifier
and our school's web-based compiler just says 
Unexpected character: ;    Unrecognized C syntax

The errors occur when compiling, and start at the first statement in main

Comment: I think your code, as a result of copy-and-paste, has some hidden characters that are causing this compiler errors. Try retyping the lines that are causing this error and it should compile.

Comment: Thanks! That solved it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.While you are calling the function from main() don't use [] to array.
2.As you are not getting values in command line then use only int main()

i.e.

```
int main()
    {
        int arr1[] = { 23, 21, 20, 27 };
        int arr2[] = { 5, 7, 9, 11, 13 };

            // Print the values in the first array, fill that array with
            // its indexes, and then print the values of the array
            // again.

            printArrayValues(arr1, 4);
            fillWithIndex(arr1, 4);
            printArrayValues(arr1, 4);

            // Do similarly for the second array.

            printArrayValues(arr2, 5);
            fillWithIndex(arr2, 5);
            printArrayValues(arr2, 5);

            return 0;
    }
```

Comment: That definitely helped, looks like the other error was some hidden characters somehow. Thanks for the information!

Comment: Why should anyone use `int main()`? Proper signature is `int main(void)`. Empty parameter list is so K&R...

Comment: even if you don't write void explicitly complier grant it as void..So why unnecessary effort we bother about? even int is not necessary..you just can say main(). Just like void if don't mention the return type compiler by default make it int

Comment: @AndrewWatson: no, that's not true for C (only C++) - in C an empty parameter list means and unspecified parameter list (which can be 0 or more parameters), not void.

Comment: Can you provide any link where you gather that information? I highly doubt about it. I never knew that considered as unspecified. I'm not turning down though. You may be right. But do provide a link for credibility.

Comment: You are probably referring to #6.7.6.3 of C standard, item #14: "An empty
list in a function declarator that is part of a definition of that function specifies that the function has no parameters." but you missed the reference to #6.11.6 in footnote 145: "The use of function declarators with empty parentheses (not prototype-format parameter
type declarators) is an obsolescent feature."

Comment: @PaulR I guess you are right if the empty parameter list is found in a function declaraion instead of a function definition.

Answer (score 1):

Array decays to pointer to its first element. First argument of both of your functions expects an argument of type `int *`. In your function calls you should pass the first argument like this

```
printArrayValues(arr1, 4);
fillWithIndex(arr1, 4);
printArrayValues(arr1, 4);

// Do similarly for the second array.

printArrayValues(arr2, 5);
fillWithIndex(arr2, 5);
printArrayValues(arr2, 5);
```

Note that, you do not need subscript operator in your function call. Empty subscript operator is only valid when it is used as a parameter in function declaration/definition or when declared with an initializer list.